# Which IPs to allow in Azure for Github Actions?

Tags: azure, ip, github-actions

I have an Azure storage account. When I allow all networks to it, my Github Actions can run and update my Azure static website.

When I disallow all but named networks (147.243.0.0/16 and my machine's IP) I get a 403 (request denied) error in Github Actions.

I assume I need to add GitHub to these IPs but when I run:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/meta
```

there are tons of IPs! Do I need to add them all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you want to allow the GitHub Actions runner access to your storage account? Then yes, since that is potentially a large fleet of VMs, there are ton of IPs you would need to whitelist.

The alternative is to use a few tasks inside your pipeline:

1. look up the IP of the runner, e.g. using https://api.ipify.org
2. Add this IP to the allow-list using [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli#managing-ip-network-rules)
3. Do your actual work on storage
4. Remove the allow entry again through CLI

Example Code:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Azure
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  publish:
    environment: Production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Whitelist GitHub Runner IP
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            set -eu
            agentIP=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)
            az storage account network-rule add \
              --resource-group "${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" \
              --account-name "${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}" \
              --ip-address $agentIP
            sleep 300

      - name: Upload to blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            set -eu
            az storage blob upload-batch \
              --account-name "${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}" \
              --source ./src/ \
              --destination '$web' \
              --overwrite true

      - name: Purge CDN endpoint
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            set -eu
            az cdn endpoint purge \
              --content-paths  "/*"  \
              --profile-name "${{ secrets.CDN_PROFILE_NAME }}" \
              --name "${{ secrets.CDN_ENDPOINT }}" \
              --resource-group "${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}"

      - name: Remove GitHub Runner IP from Whitelist
        if: always()
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            set -eu
            agentIP=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)
            az storage account network-rule remove  \
              --resource-group "${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" \
              --account-name "${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}" \
              --ip-address $agentIP

      - name: logout
        if: always()
        run: |
          az logout
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When you say, "look up the IP of the runner", what is the runner? All the Github IPs?

Comment: The runner is the VM that got a particular job to execute - it runs your Action

Comment: The 300 sleep is a little but much. You can get away with 30.

Comment: Best answer indeed, at the moment the list of runner ranges is about 1000 entries, while the maximum number of entries for an AppService slot is 512.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can assign [fixed IP address for your runners](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-01-github-actions-larger-runners-are-now-in-public-beta/). This is in beta, but now doable

> Fixed IP ranges
>
> Setup a fixed IP range for your machines by simply ticking a check box, this provides an IP range that can be allow listed in internal systems and in GitHub’s allow list to keep using Actions while making your GitHub environment more secure.
>
> [image]

Comment: This [requires a GitHub Enterprise Cloud subscription](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-larger-runners/managing-larger-runners#creating-static-ip-addresses-for-larger-runners)